# O que significa handshake?

Tags: http, terminologia, websocket

Ao estudar sobre [WebSocket](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), li a seguinte frase:

> Sua única relação com o HTTP é que seu handshake é interpretado por servidores HTTP como uma requisição de *upgrade*.

- Nesse contexto, o que significa handshake?
- Na prática, o que significa "...seu *handshake* é interpretado por servidores HTTP como uma requisição de Upgrade"?

Comment: Significa um bom aperto de mão... pronto, troféu piada nerd do ano pra mim.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90957/web-server-tls-ssl-handshake

Comment: Handshake é o nome do processo utilizado para estabelecer a conexão HTTP. Tipo, quando o cliente e o servidor se encontram e falam um "oi" um para o outro e apertam as mãos para se cumprimentar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aperto de mão :P

> Nesse contexto, o que significa handshake?

É a comunicação inicial entre duas aplicações que vão se comunicar. Durante o processo de [*handshaking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking) cada uma das aplicações vão "negociando" como eles vão trabalhar, um passa como deseja se comunicar dentro de determinados parâmetros [especificados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177519/101) e o outro diz se aceita ou nega ou oferece alternativas para o outro lado decidir o que aceita. Se eles conseguirem entrar em acordo a comunicação propriamente dita começa.

O processo pode ocorrer durante a transmissão de dados após cada passo. Um lado pode confirmar o recebimento conforme foi combinado.

Tem mais detalhes sobre o HTTP em [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/101).

> Na prática, o que significa "...seu handshake é interpretado por servidores HTTP como uma requisição de Upgrade"?

Essa [requisição de upgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header) é algo que o HTTP usa para indicar que vai usar algo novo ao protocolo, então o HTTP passa ser usado apenas como transporte.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A segunda questão me deixou um pouco confuso. Criei socket utilizando o `WebSocket` do HTML5. No lado do servidor utilizei uma lib PHP (apenas para testes). Ao abrir o HTML no browser, utilizei o inspector de elementos do Chrome e na aba `Network` reparei que existe apenas um request: `Request URL:ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echobot`. Não vi nada relacionado ao HTTP, pelo menos nos logs do Chrome. Como o HTTP foi utilizado?

Comment: O *request* é HTTP, o WebSocket vai encapsulado dentro dele.